# Struggling with Gradle Plugin for Configuring MultiProject Build

Tags: java, gradle, groovy, plugins

I've got my multi-project reusable build plugin built and published and my first project build is consuming it, but I don't understand why this doesn't work the way I think it should:

```
    class TdkGradlePlugin implements Plugin<Project> 
    {
        void apply(Project project)     
        {
            project.subprojects 
            {
                ...  // entire multiproject reusable build code for sub-projects here
            }
        }
    }
```

There are a host of different complaints from gradle about this, but I'm thinking it's most likely that you just can't do this. If I can't do this, how do I encorporate all this logic in my plugin? It's several pages of gradle code defining how to build all my projects and it all worked 100% before I tried to move it into the plugin. This code looks roughly like this:

```
    project.subprojects 
    {
        apply plugin: 'java-library'
        apply plugin: 'maven-publish'
        
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_11    
        
        dependencies 
        {
           ...
        }
        
        tasks.withType(Javadoc).all 
        { 
            enabled = false 
        }
                
        clean.doFirst
        {
            ...
        }
        
        apply plugin: 'eclipse'
            
        eclipse 
        {
            ...
        }
            
        processResources 
        {
            ...
        }
          
        compileJava 
        {
            ...
        }

        etc ...
```

Thanks for any helpful hints!

```
Jon
```

Comment: does your custom plugin actually have any custom behaviour ?  if all you need is`subprojects { common steps }` you don't need to write plugin - just put that whole section in the root project.  If you still want to write - then you can't copy the groovy dsl directly, you will need to write java equivalent syntax.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that I can't use the DSL in the plugin code. That wasn't 100% clear to me. I've already got it working for one tree of projects (multiproject build). The problem is that I have dozens of trees of multibuild projects that need to share a common build configuration. In maven this is easy with the superpom. It's unclear how to get the same out of gradle. There have been some sharp edges with the transition, but this is the sharpest so far.

Comment: @PrasadU Not exactly true; one can use Java, Groovy, or Kotlin (or, as I understand it, any JVM language) to write Gradle plugins. And as [noted here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/index.html), the build script is essentially operating on `Project` and `Script` objects. Since a plugin has access to the `Project` instance the code can look remarkably like the DSL—particularly if the plugin is written in Groovy or Kotlin.

Comment: @Jon There are ways to create plugins other than standalone projects. Check out https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/custom_plugins.html. For instance, you can simply create separate scripts and apply them to projects as needed. The other option is to use regular programming logic (e.g. `if` blocks) in the `build.gradle` file to only apply configuration to certain (sub-)projects.